# Add images programatically to Magento Products 1.6.1

Tags: php, image, magento

I had recently imported over 1000 products from osCommerce to Magento 1.6.1, now all I need to do is to assign the default thumb image to each, all of them got an image and it shows on the product page, however the thumbs are not set and I have to set them manually on each product, I know it is possible to make this with some code all at once, but not so sure how to do it.

I don't want to export and import again as CSV, since it got html on descriptions, etc and the CSV always breaks putting everything on the wrong columns.

I will appreciate some help, and if I got to create a .php file I will also appreciate if you also include the includes I need to do.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to import all columns in the csv. In fact, for updating, I believe you only will need to use 'sku'. Then just specify the thumbnail image in a second column and import that.

Try importing it with the same filenames as you used for the main image. Magento is supposed to process the images into thumbnails automatically. There are also some good import extensions.

Comment: Will try it out!, managed to export to csv without the description so it is looking good, will do a backup  before importing, and lets hope for the best :)

Comment: You might have to refresh the cache for it to show up. If it still doesn't work, I just had another idea. I haven't imported images in awhile and I just remembered something. You might have to specify "store_view" or something like that when importing images in order for them to show up properly. In addition to "sku" and "thumbs" (or whatever it's called), add in the columns for store view and websites. Try importing that and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

i do this via the API. With catalog_product_attribute_media.create

my newImage Array looks like this:

```
$newImage = array(
    'file' => array(
        'name' => 'file_name',
        'content' => base64_encode(file_get_contents('product.jpg')), // you can indicate your oscommerce link to the image
        'mime'    => 'image/jpeg'
    ),
    'label'    => 'testimage',
    'position' => 2,
    'types'    => array('thumbnail'),
    'exclude'  => 0
);
```

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/catalog_product_attribute_media#catalog_product_attribute_media.create
for futher information.

The call is with your Magento ProductSKU and the NewArray. You should do a query to your OsCommerce Database to get the right Image for the SKU.

Regards boti

Comment: How quickly does that run? Does API make use of the dataflow import method or the new faster method. dataflow is ridiculously slow so any way around it is good.